# Please recommend the dictionary application or the file format to start with

Tags: language-agnostic, macos, dictionary, cross-platform

I want to write a simple application like the "stardict" (but not so huge), that searches for the phrase in the dictionary and provides the corresponding value.

I guess that it is kind of "bicycle" and that it was done many times by different people... But the thing is that all the suitable open software, that is available in the web is the "stardict" and it is just incredibly ugly for me personally.
I think that I can write some back-end, that searches for articles in the dictionary and just provides the result in plain form. And the second app, the front-end would just present the result on the screen in acceptable form.

**Please recommend the dictionary application the file format to start with, I just want to hear suggestions from my fellow programmers.**

Requirements: *free, open, has converters to and from popular formats*.

P.S. The Apple's "Dictionary" would be just perfect, but it cannot search for the phrase. So if anyone knows how to extend it with "plugins", just let me know. This app is not free, but it is acceptable also.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of Unix spell/ispell and the like?

Comment: No, I have no idea about available options... That's why I've asked this question.